# mysql in clause using a subquery for the list - much slower execution time than hard coding the list

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery, query-optimization

I have a query that looks something like this (simplified version)

```
SELECT 
  title,
  count(title) c,
  SUM(
    id IN 
    (SELECT 
      otherID 
    FROM
      otherTable 
    WHERE someTrait IN (18, 19, 29, 20, 21, 30))
  ) s 
from
  `TABLE` 
  GROUP BY title
  HAVING t-s > 0
```

It takes 2 seconds to run the first couple times, then runs in about .15 seconds after being cached, but will sometimes bounce back to 2 seconds after repeated execution

Now, say I take the subquery

```
SELECT 
  otherID 
FROM
  otherTable 
WHERE someTrait IN (18, 19, 29, 20, 21, 30)
```

and I get a result in .1 seconds. Here is the result:

```
(1,27,145,600,1234)
```

so I sub that in to the original query for this

```
SELECT 
  title,
  count(title) t,
  SUM(id IN (1, 27, 145, 600, 1234)) s
FROM
  `TABLE`
GROUP BY title
HAVING t-s > 0
```

It takes .6 seconds to run the first time, then between 0.05 and 0.15 seconds after repeated execution, but never spikes up to the full .6 seconds the way the first query does.

**Why does MySQL take a longer time to run the first query?** Is there a proper *"MySql way"* to do what I have done, that is, to get the result of the subquery, save it, and put that directly into my other query?

I am using php, so at the moment I am making the first query, storing the result to a comma seperated value string, and passing it to the second query, but I feel like there
should be a better approach, or there is some key point about MySql I am missing.

On that note, I like to use a `JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `IN` when I can, but since it is an argument to `SUM` I didn't see how to do that either.

Comment: Well it takes longer to run because you are doing two IN() 's that are all summed. IN is really slow especially in comparison to a join so having two IN() 's in your SUM() will definitely make it run slowly. will the results of your subquery be the same all the time? because if those can change then it would probably be a bad idea to hardcode the numbers returned from the subquery. I'm not really sure what you're trying to do with this query, but i'll bet theres a better way to lay it out

Comment: the first query has to do the innermost IN() comparison with that select for each number. and then repeated for however many times the outer IN() goes, then does a SUM() of that

Comment: the result of the subquery does change over time, but it is slow relative to the execution time of the script; the result might change every day or 2 but the script theoretically runs in a few hours. in the way that i save the intermediate result in php, is there a way to do that in pure mysql?

Comment: you can do a stored procedure yes and make variables in mysql that you can pass in the IN() if you like

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/local-variable-scope.html